# How to update the playback time of an audio when it is playing, using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: xcode

I want to show the playback time / total duration on a label, of an audio when it is playing. I have seen AVAudioPlayerDelegate methods, but I cannot find such method for this, which notifies to it on every second after playing. I do it like this:

```
-(IBAction)playAudio{

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *audioPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"PhirMohobat" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *audioUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];


player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audioUrl error:NULL]; 
player.delegate = self;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[player play];

}

-(void)updateTime
{

float minutes = floor(player.currentTime/60);
float seconds = player.currentTime - (minutes * 60);

float duration_minutes = floor(player.duration/60);
float duration_seconds = player.duration - (duration_minutes * 60);

NSString *timeInfoString = [[NSString alloc] 
                            initWithFormat:@"%0.0f.%0.0f / %0.0f.%0.0f",
                            minutes, seconds, 
                            duration_minutes, duration_seconds];


timerLabel.text = timeInfoString;
[timeInfoString release];
```

}

Is there any implicit delegate method to do this in AVAudioPlayer or any other audio player supported by xcode?

Answer (score 2):

AVAudioPlayer has a property named currentTime, so you could ask in a certain interval using a NSTimer what is actual value of this property and then update according to this value whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks For your answer but i have tried it early and interested in new approach I want an explicit callback or any other library that provide it without using a timer